# How do I use Mean Value Theorem to proof that the speed equals the average speed?

Tags: calculus

I was watching a lecture and the example given: a car travelled 240 miles in 3 hours and during the interval of [0, 3], there is at least once that the speed equals the average speed.

How do I use the Mean Value Theorem to proof this example?

Please pardon me for asking the answer as I am self-learning Calculus by watching videos.

Comment: A good first step in questions like this is to look at the theorem you're supposed to use. Then try to see what parts of the theorem apply to what parts of the question, and how.

Comment: @DavidK I find it quite hard to grasp the concepts when I am self-studying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the trajectory of the car as a differentiable function $d(x)$, with $x\in[0,3]$. Then, by the mean value theorem there is an $x_0\in(0,3)$ that

$$\frac{d(3)-d(0)}{3-0}=d'(x_0),$$

where $d(3)=240$ and $d(0)=0$. So in the left hand you get the average speed, and in the right hand is the speed in some specific time. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the following:

Can the speed be always strictly less than the average speed?

Comment: And similarly, can the speed always be strictly greater than the average speed?...Then from these two answers we would get some conclusion....